# ReferenceError:gapi is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am seeing `ReferenceError:gapi is not defined` error when accessing the `Google+ APIs` from my HTML code.

My code is very simple, but not sure what is wrong with it.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Please see my code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Some title here </title>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
        <script>
            function handleClientLoad(){
                gapi.client.setApiKey('MY API KEY HERE')};
        </script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?  onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error is

> Execution failed: ReferenceError: "gapi" is not defined

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the answer, but I notice that there is a space between "client.js?" and "onload=". This might not be in your original code, but it does cause the client.js request to return different code.

Comment: There is no space in the original code. Thanks for looking at my issue David.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue. I should have added more details to the question but didnt thought that the issue could be somewhere else. Sorry for the same.

When we create a Web App project in Google Drive, the javascript code which runs on the server and the code which runs on the client(a browser) should be specified in different files. These files are Code.gs and JavaScript.html respectively. "gapi" is a client code (defined in client.js) and I was referencing to it in the server file. Since server code is running in the Google servers, it has no clue about our client.js and platform.js libraries. Hence the error. When I moved the error causing code to JavaScript.html, it worked fine.

Thanks.,